# CSS not reflecting on web page while running node server

Tags: css, node.js

I have created a server on nodejs and sent an HTML file as a response. In the html file, I have linked a css file but it is not reflecting while running the server.
The web page behaves like a plain html file.

Here is the html code -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bool.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="creamy">
            <h1 style="font-size: xx-large;">Anindya Ram Tripathi</h1>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

here is css code -

```
    .creamy {
        color: aqua;
    }
```

Here is server code -

```
    const http = require("http");
    const fs = require("fs");

    fs.readFile("./bool.html", function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err.message;
    } else {
        const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        handleServer(req, res);
        });

        function handleServer(req, res) {
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
        }

        server.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("Server listening to port 3000!");
        });
    }
    });
```

Comment: What does `router.css(req, res);` do?  Is that where you expect CSS files to be served?  If so, then why are you doing `res.write(html)` on every incoming request, including requests for CSS files?  Also looks like you're not setting a `content-type`.

Comment: CSS is still not showing on the web page even after including the content-type to text/html.  router.css was not in the code it's included by mistake.

Comment: Then, you have no http server route that serves your CSS file.  Your http server only sends one file, your HTML file.  So, when it gets a request for the CSS file, it just sends the HTML file and that isn't CSS so it fails.

Answer (score -1):

Add below code in your main file

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

create css directory in public directory and your CSS inport code will be like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bool.css">
```

Comment: The OP is not using Express.  They are using a plain http server coded without a framework.